# Parsing XML files to get particular text content

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am parsing the XML files which represents research papers / artciles and have below XML schema to store in a MYSQL database in Java

```
  <article>
    <article-meta></article-meta>
    <body>
     <p> 
     Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a markup language that defines a set of
     rules for encoding documents in a format that is both human-readable and machine-
     readable <ref id = 1>. It is defined in the XML 1.0 Specification produced by the 
      W3C, and several other related specifications
      </p>
      <p>
       Many application programming interfaces (APIs) have been developed to aid 
      software developers with processing XML <ref id = 2>. data, and several schema 
       systems exist to aid in the definition of XML-based languages.
      </p>
    </body>
    <back>
      <ref-list>
         <ref id = 1>Details about this reference </ref>
         <ref id = 2>Details about this reference </ref>
       </ref-list>
     </back>
   </article>
```

I am parsing the files using DOM parser . One of the requirements is for every **ref id** , i have to extract 150 characters form left and right from the location where it is referred in the  body tags. How can I do this ??

```
     refId     leftText    rightText
     1         left 150     150 chars on right side
```

Comment: Do a search for xPath

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got the `<ref>` tag element `Id = 1` and element `content value = Details about this reference` from xml in your code using dom, storing `<ref> tag` content value in a string variable then you can use sub string method to get left char and right char like this.

```
String text ="Details about this reference";
String leftText = text.substring(0,7); // get 7 chars from left side
String rightText =text.substring(text.length()-2); // get 2 char from right side, instead of 2 you have to pass10
```

result

```
leftText:Details rightText:ce
```

Note: you need to check string length grater than 150 before extracting it, if less than substring will throw exception ArayIndexBoundOfException

Comment: I have to extract it from the body . For example for `<ref>` tag element `Id =1` ,left and right characters would be both ------- ** human-readable and machine-readable <ref id = 1>. It is defined in the XML 1.0 Specification**

Comment: Have you extract the ref tag content value.